# Adding NAudio controls to toolbox

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5, naudio, waveform

I am trying to use the controls from NAudio library such as WaveViewer, VolumeMeter, VolumeSlider, Fader, WaveformPainter etc. I am using Visual Studio 2012 and have net 4.5 installed. I have also downloaded and referenced NAudio 1.7 and its .dll to my project. When I right click on toolbox and click on choose items, navigate to .NET components tab and choose browse, click on the NAudion dll and then check these new controls to add, a message box appears with the following error:

Controls Fader, PanSlider, Pot, VolumeMeter, VolumeSlider, WaveformPainter, WaveViewer were added.
Make sure the controls added are compatible with the current designer and .NET Framework version.

I have tried resetting the toolbox and re-adding these controls.

I am using VS2012 to create a WPF project to play a video and also show it waveform below (I have already extracted the audio into a .wav file which I wish to show by using one of the controls from NAudio if I could only get these controls to be enabled - not grayed out - in the designer's toolbox.)

I am a new to c# and WPF and to NAudio so any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are Windows Forms controls, not WPF controls. NAudio does include a WPF demo application which contains some bits you could reuse, and also the [.NET Voice Recorder](http://voicerecorder.codeplex.com) application shows how to display waveforms and volume meters in WPF while using NAudio.

Comment: Thank you @MarkHeath for clarifying that. I will be sure to check out the WPF demo app code.